# ASX stock feed - showing array cant remove

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to add a yahoo stock feed to my site. I can get the price to show, but it prints some unneccassary text when only i want is the price

This is the function in wordpress

```
function getStock($quote='GOOG')
{
$file = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$quote.AX&f=l1";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ','))
     print_r($data);    
fclose($handle);
}
```

And this is what it outputs

```
 Array ( 
   [0] => 0.110 
  )
```

Its nearly there, just need to remove everthing except the 0.110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `print_r($data)`
with

```
$d = array_shift($data); print_r($d);
```